# Finding submodule commits that never got pushed to a public repository

Tags: git, shell, git-submodules

Can someone help me fill in the missing pieces to a script I'm trying to write?  I just realized that I have a public repository that contains references to commits in a submodule that I never pushed to origin (the commits were reorganized before pushing).  I don't know how many times it's happened, but I'd like to find out and create temporary branches to push to origin.

So, back to the script.  I know that I can get a list of commits with changes to my submodule, which I could filter with `grep` and use `cut` to get the actual SHA1 tags from `my_submodule`:

```
git log -u origin/master -- my_submodule \
    | grep "^\+Subproject" \
    | cut -d" " -f 3
```

At that point, I had 20 tags and I just used a text editor to make a script to manually tag each one with "tag_00xx".  Then I manually reviewed the repository in Git Extensions and deleted any tags for commits that had made it into origin/master, leaving the one tag that had never been pushed.

What should I have done to only create tags for commits that weren't in origin/master?  I know that I can do:

```
git branch -r --contains <commit_sha1>
```

But that doesn't set an exit code I can use to selectively create new tags.  How could I have completed the automation of my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do this in the following way - first, you can list all the committed submodule versions without the `grep` and `cut` by doing:

```
git rev-list origin/master | while read COMMIT
do
    SUBMODULE_COMMIT=$(git rev-parse $COMMIT:my_submodule 2> /dev/null)
    if [ $? = 0 ]
    then
        echo $SUBMODULE_COMMIT
    fi
done | sort | uniq > committed-submodule-versions
```

Then, for each of those, you need to change into the submodule and check if it's in `origin/master`.  Probably the simplest way to do that is to grep the output of `git branch -r --contains <SUBMODULE-COMMIT>`, since then you can use `grep`'s exit code.

For example:

```
cd my_submodule
while read S
do
    if git rev-parse --verify $S > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
    then
        git branch -r --contains $S 2> /dev/null \
            | grep origin/master > /dev/null \
            || git branch missing-${S:0:8} $S
    else
        echo $S not found in the repository at all
    fi

done < ../committed-submodule-versions
```

Another point to note is that I'm creating *branches* for the unpushed commits rather than tags.  The reason for this is that `git submodule update` causes a `git fetch`, but not a `git fetch --tags`, which means that tags that don't point at known commits won't be fetched (!).

Comment: Thank you Mark, for such a thorough answer that combines some advanced shell scripting with a better understanding of git than what I have...  I also appreciate the note about using branches instead of tags.